# How do you create a relational association with an existing row of data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I couldn't find any info of this in the Ruby on Rails documentation, and couldn't find anything online as well. How do you add a relation to an existing row of data?

Word model:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :synonyms, class_name: "Word", foreign_key: "word_id", join_table: "word_synonyms", association_foreign_key: "synonym_id"
end
```

Rails Console:

```
word = Word.create(name:'test')
word.synonyms.create(name:"experiment") # This is how I would associate it normally

new_word = Word.create(name:'rate')

#How do I associate word with new_word?
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the `new_word` in the `word.synonyms` array like such:

`word.synonyms << new_word`

Answer (score 0):

```
word = Word.create(name:'test')
word.synonyms.create(name:"experiment")

new_word = Word.create(name:'rate')
word.synonyms << new_word
```